# Set images duration in FFmpeg when converting a list of images to one video?

Tags: python, shell, ffmpeg

I achieved my need by converting a list of images within a folder to one video using this cmd

```
ffmpeg  -framerate 1 -loop 1 -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg' -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 12 video.mp4;
```

I just need to set a duration for example 6s for each image! Is this possible using FFmpeg?

Comment: I am looking for the same thing along with adding background music to generated video. Spend the last week on research but not getting anything related to this. :-(  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69597463/can-we-add-background-music-and-framerate-on-generated-video-using-ffmpeg-tool-i

Comment: @KunalPatel the solution i've found, is to create video for each image and then merge them together, you can use the final video and merge it with the music you want!

Comment: @KunalPatel your question is based on .net. That is possibly why there are no quick replies. With a straightforward ffmpeg command adding audio is very simple to do and there are numerous answers on SO and SuperUser that explain that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play each frame for 6 seconds use `-framerate 1/6`. Also, `-loop 1` is not required unless you want the files to all finish encoding once and then start over at the beginning.

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1/6 -pattern_type glob -i "*.jpg" -vcodec libx264 \
-pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 -threads 4 -crf 25 -refs 1 -bf 0 -coder 0 -g 25 \
-keyint_min 15 -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

You can change -crf etc to your requirements.